# Check for exceptions before returing the string value from the query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, postgresql, npgsql

My function causes alot of exception, therefore performace is not that great.

Could you advise on how to fix the function and validate the data before I return the string back? I have tried to see if amount of tables are more than 0, but this is not always the case.

```
    public String getString(String sql)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", tbHost, tbPort, tbUser, tbPass, tbDataBaseName);
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            ds.Reset();
            da.Fill(ds);           
            conn.Close();
            return ds.Tables.Count == 0 ? "0" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exceptions are being thrown?  What should the calling method do if an exception is encountered?

Comment: Don't assign variables values outside of the try block and move the .Close() to a finally block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to automatically dispose of objects you create. You might explicitly open/close connections, but it is not needed here because the behaviour will be exactly the same. DataAdapter will open connection if not opened and remember to close it afterwards.

About `validate the data` - see comments in code.

```
public String getString(String sql)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    {
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", tbHost, tbPort, tbUser, tbPass, tbDataBaseName);
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            using (NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
            {
                da.Fill(ds);
                // You did check count of tables
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                   DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
                   // But forgot to check count of Rows
                   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                   {
                      object o = dt.Rows[0][0];
                      //  And returned value for nulls
                      //  Check for null is here because I don't know
                      //  This Postgresql classes
                      if (o != DBNull.Value && o != null)
                      {
                         return o.ToString();
                      }
                  }
              }
           }
        }
    }
    // Return default value
    return "0";
}
```

One final thing - when testing enumeration, don't convert it to string. To see if connection is opened, simply say:

```
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
```

Answer (score 1):

try using a "finally" block as well.

Also I would recommend to divide the Connect functionality to a other method to have better control of where an exception would occur.

Also use stored procedures with SQL to minimize errors with the SQL string.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getString(String sql)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", tbHost, tbPort, tbUser, tbPass, tbDataBaseName);
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
    conn.Open();
    NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    ds.Reset();
    try
    {
       da.Fill(ds);          
    }
    catch (Exception msg)
    {
        // do something here or log the error.
    }
    finally
    {
       if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
       {
            conn.Close();
       }
    }
    return ds.Tables.Count == 0 ? "0" : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: For correctness, I would do something in that empty catch block!

Comment: ACK!!! You should never have an empty catch!  Perhaps you meant to put `//Log error`

Comment: guys I assumed that it is obvious to do some thing in the catch block., any ways I have updated the answer